# Use 3G modem on Intel Galileo Gen 2

Tags: linux, modem, 3g

I'm working on a project and I use Intel Galileo Gen 2 with Yocto Project Linux. I use LAN to connect to Internet but I would want to connect to Internet with 3G USB modem.

I tried using Sakis3G to connect my 3G USB modem with my Intel Galileo and use Internet through it. But I couldn't install it.

I don't want to use any additional hardware or shields, only through software.

Can you suggest and help me to create an Internet connection using 3G USB modem?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can configure your 3G modem without added software , just set up a mobile broadband connection (e;g) On Debian from the connection editor clic add and choose  **mobile broadband**  , make sur that your device is detected and follow the assistant

2) You can install `modem-manager-gui`

for example

[debian](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/modem-manager-gui) : `sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui`

Arch-linux :`pacman -S modem-manager-gui` ....

for ubuntu you need to add a new ppa:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxonly/modem+manager+gui 
 sudo apt-get update
```

to install:

```
sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui
```